# HTTP status code for GET request with non-existing query parameter value

Tags: rest, http, api-design, http-status-codes

Let's clarify three common scenarios when no item matches the request with a simple example:

1. `GET /posts/{postId}` and `postId` does not exist (status code 404, no question)
2. `GET /posts?userId={userId}` and the user with `userId` does not have any posts
3. `GET /posts?userId={userId}` and the user with `userId` does not exist itslef

I know there's no strict REST guideline for the appropriate status codes for cases 2 and 3, but it seems to be a common practice to return `200` for case 2 as it's considered a "search" request on the `posts` resource, so it is said that `404` might not be the best choice.

Now I wonder if there's a common practice to handle case 3. Based on a similar reasoning with case 2, `200` seems to be more relevant (and of course in the response body more info could be provided), although returning `404` to highlight the fact that `userId` itself does not exist is also tempting.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first, REST doesn't say anything about what the endpoints should return. That's the HTTP spec. The HTTP spec says that if you make a request for a non-existent resource, the proper response code is `404`.

Case 1 is a request for a single thing. That would return `404`, as you said.

The resource being returned in case 2 is typically an envelope which contains metadata and a collection of things. It doesn't matter if the envelope has any things in it or not. So `200` is the correct response code because the envelope exists, it just so happens the envelope isn't holding any things. It would be allowable under the spec to say there's no envelope if there are no things and return `404`, but that's usually not done because then the API can't send the metadata.

Case 3, then, is exactly the same thing as case 2. If expected response is an envelope, then the envelope exists whether or not the `userId` is valid. It would not be unreasonable to include metadata in the envelope pointing out that there is no user with `userId`, if the API designer thinks that information would be useful to clients.

Case 2 and Case 3 are really the same case, and should both either return `200` with an empty envelope or `404`.

Answer (score 0):

First piece, you need to recognize that `/posts?userId={userId}` identifies a [resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1), precisely in the same sense that `/posts/{userId}` or `/index.html` specifies a resource.

So `GET /posts?userId={userId}` "requests transfer of a current selected representation for the target resource."

The distinction between 200 and 404 is straight forward; if you are reporting to the consumer that "the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists", then you should be returning [404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4).  If the response payload includes a current representation of the resource, then you should use the [200](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) status code.

404 is, of course, an response from the [Client Error response class](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5)

> the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.

So *a* way of figuring out which of these status codes to use, is to just look at the message body of the response.  If it is a current representation of the resource, then you use the 200 status code.  If it is a representation of a message that explains no current representation is available, then you use the 404 status code.

Of course that ducks the big question: what should the representation of the resource be in each case?  Once you know that, you can work out the rest.

If you you think that an unexpected identifier indicates an error on the client (for example, a corrupted link), then it will probably improve the consumer's experience to report that as an explicit error, rather than returning a representation of an empty list.

But that's a judgment call; different API are going to have different answers, and HTTP isn't particularly biased one way or the other; HTTP just asks that you ensure that the response code and headers are appropriate for the choice that you have made.